# Using Masonry as a Nuxt.js plugin client side

Tags: ecmascript-6, nuxt.js, masonry

I'm trying to get Masonry working in a Nuxt website I'm building. I only need it to load on client side, and I'm having trouble getting that to work.

I think the underlying problem is that Masonry auto-initializes itself and looks for data attributes in the HTML, so if it runs server side it will crash because `window` doesn't exist. I thought I understood how Nuxt works, but this is making me question everything! LOL!

So first I create a plugin, and load it client side only:
[image: nuxt.config.js file]

And then I import the masonry package, and export it. My understanding is this would only run client side now.
[image: nuxt plugin file content]

And then in my component I import the plugin:
[image]

Doing this will crash the server with a window undefined error from Masonry. Why?! It should be loading the plugin only client side?!
[image]

I've actually got this to work by not using the plugin steps, and doing this in my component:

```
 let Masonry
 if (process.client) {
     Masonry = require("masonry-layout")
 }
```

But that seems like a very un-Nuxt way to do things.

So how should I be doing this? I really don't want to have to use the popular Vue-Masonry package (it forces no-ssr of the HTML on Nuxt) and it has a lot of layout bugs, also I really wanted to use this as a way to understand Nuxt better.

Should I not use Nuxt plugins to do this? Is it better to just throw the script into the head and use it like regular JS with a process.client check?

Comment: As you've registered it as a plugin in nuxt.config.js you don't need to import it into individual components. This may be where your issue is.

Comment: Thanks @Andrew1325, I fixed that. Now I get an `this is undefined` error from  `this.element = queryElement` in Masonry, so perhaps Masonry is just not setup to work this way.